# Disk drive not recognized by laptop

Tags: hard-drive, usb, windows-8.1, sata

I have an external USB drive. Took it apart and got the internal drive. Used it as normal on my desktop. Put it back together and tried to use it on a laptop.

The laptop recognizes the drive but does not give a drive letter.

In computer management it simply says GPT Protected Partition.

Does not show that it is an NTFS partition like it does on the desktop and all property options are grayed out.

Both are using windws 8.1 x64 and the drive is 4TB.

Again, the drive works fine on the desktop both as USB ext and SATA int. The drive doesn't function properly on the laptop as USB(haven't tried SATA).

Any ideas what is going on?

BTW, if I put a different disk in the SATA to USB adapter part of the external HD enclosure, it works fine. Seems to be some specific issue with the drive and the laptop... probably because it is 4TB, but, again, works on the desktop and same OS.

Comment: Is teh laptop on legacy BIOS or UEFI?

Comment: @BenPlont legacy